Illegal State Application Context Failure Threshold while running Spring Boot tests using Mockito
I am getting Illegal State Application Context Failure Threshold error while running my spring boot project tests. It seems like my code is able to fetch the context of the application and facing issues with Security Configurations. I am new to using mockito with Spring Framework. Any help would be appreciated greatly.
Here is my code -
UserController.java
@RestController
public class UserInfoController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserInfoService userInfoService; 
    
    @GetMapping("/userDetail")
public ResponseEntity<?> getUserDetail(@RequestParam("user") String user) {
    return userService.getUserDetails(user);
}
}

UserInfo.java
private String user;
private String workstation;
private String status;
private String message;

public UserInfo() {
    
}

public UserInfo(String user, String workstation) {
    super();
    this.user = user;
    this.workstation = workstation;
    this.status = "Success";
    this.message = "User exists in database and has access to given workstation";
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getWorkstation() {
    return workstation;
}

public void setWorkstation(String workstation) {
    this.workstation = workstation;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

}
Application.properties
users.admin=abc
users.staff=abc

app2Url=http://localhost:8080/app2

ConfigSecurity.java
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class ConfigSecurity extends WebSecurityConfiguration{

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/userDetail").authenticated())
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
    }
    
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .build();
    }
    
}

UserService.java
    @Service
public class UserService {
    
    @Value("#{${users}}")
    private Map<String, String> userInfoProperties;
    
    @Value("${appName2Url}")
    private String appName2Url;
    
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public ResponseEntity<?> getUserDetails(String user) {
        if (userInfoProperties.containsKey(user)) {
            String workstation = userInfoProperties.get(user);
            String url = appName2Url + "/addUserInfo";
            UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(user, workstation);
            ResponseEntity<UserInfo> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, userInfo, UserInfo.class);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response.getBody(), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("User not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
    
    public void setUserInfoProperties(Map<String, String> userInfoProperties) {
        this.userInfoProperties = userInfoProperties;
    }
    
    public void setAppName2Url(String appName2Url) {
        this.appName2Url = appName2Url;
    }
}

UserInfoServiceTest.java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@InjectMocks
private UserService userService;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    // Initialize the userInfoProperties map manually
    Map<String, String> userInfoProperties = new HashMap<>();
    userInfoProperties.put("admin", "CCUICKB0F1");
    userService.setUserInfoProperties(userInfoProperties);
    
    // Set the appName2Url manually
    userService.setAppName2Url("http://localhost:8080/appName2");
}

@Test
public void testGetUserDetails_UserExists() {
    // Set up test data
    UserInfo mockUserInfo = new UserInfo("admin", "CCUICKB0F1");
    ResponseEntity<UserInfo> mockResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(mockUserInfo, HttpStatus.OK);

    // Mock external service call
    when(restTemplate.postForEntity(eq("http://localhost:8080/appName2/addUserInfo"), any(UserInfo.class), eq(UserInfo.class)))
        .thenReturn(mockResponse);

    // Execute the method to be tested
    ResponseEntity<?> response = userService.getUserDetails("admin");

    // Verify the response
    assert(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK);
    assert(response.getBody().equals(mockUserInfo));
}

@Test
public void testGetUserDetails_UserNotFound() {
    // Set up test data for non-existing user
    Map<String, String> userInfoProperties = new HashMap<>();
    userService.setUserInfoProperties(userInfoProperties);
    
    // Set the appName2Url manually
    userService.setAppName2Url("http://localhost:8080/appName2");

    // Execute the method to be tested
    ResponseEntity<?> response = userService.getUserDetails("admin");

    // Verify the response
    assert(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    assert(response.getBody().equals("User not found"));
}

}
Sharing the stackTrace for the code -
Description:

Parameter 0 of method defaultSecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$SecurityFilterChainConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@32069394 testClass = com.assignment.UserServiceTest, locations = [], classes = [com.assignment.JaUserInfoHttpApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true", "server.port=0"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@2dcd168a, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@531f4093, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@5b1ebf56, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@5adb0db3, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@c13a210b], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180) ~[spring-test-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130) ~[spring-test-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:142) ~[spring-test-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:98) ~[spring-test-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260) ~[spring-test-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:290) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:279) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:56) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:122) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385) ~[surefire-booter-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162) ~[surefire-booter-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507) ~[surefire-booter-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495) ~[surefire-booter-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configSecurity': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'defaultSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$SecurityFilterChainConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'defaultSecurityFilterChain' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:895) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:848) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1421) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1463) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108) ~[spring-boot-test-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225) ~[spring-test-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152) ~[spring-test-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 73 common frames omitted

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 10.12 s[1;31m <<< FAILURE![m -- in com.assignment.[1mUserServiceTest[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] com.assignment.UserServiceTest.testGetUserDetails_UserNotFound -- Time elapsed: 0.034 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@32069394 testClass = com.assignment.UserServiceTest, locations = [], classes = [com.assignment.JaUserInfoHttpApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true", "server.port=0"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@2dcd168a, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@531f4093, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@5b1ebf56, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@5adb0db3, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@c13a210b], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configSecurity': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'defaultSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$SecurityFilterChainConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'defaultSecurityFilterChain' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:895)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
    ... 17 more

The code runs but the tests give error Illegal State Application Context and authenticaton issues. Please if anyone can help with a solution to it. It would be really helpful. Thanks!

of course it will be 404 - your application is not running. @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) only enables Mockito - not spring container or server.
You can use
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;


to start a server. Have a read https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web

Thanks for the reply J Asgarov. I have added the piece of code that you have shared but I am still getting error with the message as "UserServiceTest.testGetUserDetails_UserExists » IllegalState ApplicationContext failure threshold" and for the second test as well. Also, is something wrong with my configuration class? I am trying to have a basic http authentication but since antmatchers and AuthorizeRequests has been deprecated after spring 6.1, I think something is wrong with it.

that information is not enough for me to know what the issue is - please post a different question with full stacktrace. Deprecated is not a problem as long as the code compiles, you should just keep in mind that they will probably remove it in the next major version

I have updated the description and have added the stacktrace. Can you please check now and help me with these errors

we can't solve every single problem your application has under one question - that is completely unreadable, gets out out of scope and becomes very confusing. That is a DIFFERENT problem (namely correctly setting up spring security configuration), ask a new question where you post your security configuration AND stacktrace. Do some reasearch while you are at it.
